# Java Swing Button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I've written this:

```
JButton saveButton = new JButton(saveAction);
```

How do I then call it so that it displays within the window? (I've already got the code for the window, I just don't know how to call it so it shows)

Comment: Add the button to window !!??!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`saveButton.setVisible(true);`

`your_window.add(saveButton);`

Thats all.

Comment: I don't think `.setVisible(true)` is necessary here. When you display a container, components inside it are auto displayed. Until you explicitly hide them.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should create some ContentPane for window (I guess you mean JFrame). Adding a button directly to window is not a good idea :P Next you can add your button to that pane:

```
panel.addComponent(button);
```

The last thing to do is:

```
frame.setContentPane(panel)
```

And that's all :P  Just in a nutshell ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public MainWindow() throws IOException {
        setTitle("Conveyor");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 851, 515);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        JButton refreshButton = new JButton("refresh");
        contentPane.add(refreshButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
}
```